# "message": "Missing Authentication Token" Custom domain

Tags: aws-api-gateway

Everything works fine with the aws endpoint but when I try querying same API gateway through custom domain I keep getting "message": "Missing Authentication Token" error everywhere except with the root path.

I have tried different options found on the Web but with no luck. Is there some setting which permits any parameters in the URL using custom domain?

Answer (score 3):

When you see `Missing Authentication Token` with custom domain but it is working fine with the default `execute-api` domain, there are multiple places might go wrong.

1. You might be missing the basepath mapping on the custom domain, so API Gateway doesn't know which API the custom domain is mapping.
2. You might be mapping the basepath mapping on the custom domain to an API, but you don't provide the stage on the URL, the format should look like `https://<custom_domain>/<base_path>/<stage>/<resource_path>`
3. You might be mapping the basepath mapping on the custom domain to an API and a stage, but you are also providing the stage on the URL, the format should look like `https://<custom_domain>/<base_path>/<resource_path>`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I double checked what you proposed but any of these are not the case. I use Chalice framework to deploy my app, perhaps it somehow messes up permissions.

Comment: Did you have any authentication enabled on the method which you are trying to access?

Comment: Authentication was disabled but I managed to solve the problem. Read my answer below

Comment: The 3rd option solved my issue. thank you

Comment: Our problem was also fixed by nr. 3. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved after deleting everything and recreating custom domain and API again, but this time I used region eu-central-1 instead of us-east-1 in Chalice configuration and made sure that same region is active also in AWS console settings. 
I am not sure but suspect that the problem was caused because of the region settings since I changed it once before.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you included the version (for example "v0") in your path, try to remove it and try again